# getting file name and moving it

Tags: c#, .net

```
string fName = Path.GetFileName(tempPaths[z]);    
if (!File.Exists(subAch + fName))
                            {

                                File.Move(tempPaths[z], subAch + fName);
                                Console.WriteLine("moved!!! from " + tempPaths[z] + " tooooo ");


                            }
```

tempPaths is a list with all the image file paths. e.g. ./images/image4.jpg

subAch is a directory string.

I wish to get the file name of the file then move them to another directory. But with the code above i kept getting error: file is being used by other process.

Is there anyway which get the file name and move them? I have tried fileStream but was confused by it.

Please advice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work just fine. You just need to figure out who is locking the files.
I'd put the code inside the if-block in a try-catch block to deal with the locked files.
I will also recommend you to use Path.Combine instead of dir + file.

One thing: you are checking if subAch + tempPaths[z] exists, yet you are copying to a different location; subAch + fName.

Comment: THanks Ole-Brun
tempPaths[z] is the source of the original file.
subAch + fname is the destination.
if i add subAch+tempPaths[z] the whole thing will be wrong.

Could you guide me on how i would be able to check if is block?

Comment: I'm not sure it will make sense to check if the file is blocked in code. You see the file might not be blocked when you check it, but could be blocked again when trying to move the file. You should check your code to see if you might be blocking the files somewhere, or use a separate tool (like Sysinternals) to find out who is blocking the files.

Answer (score 0):

File is being used by another process means exactly that. Someone/something is already using the file, so can't move it. You can always catch the error and moving everything else?

Comment: Thanks Vincent

When i run Just Path class everything is fine. Is only when i try to put Path class and File Class together this error occurs.

i was thinking maybe the Path Class getFileName is locking the files. Is there anyway to unlock it?

Answer (score 0):

I have use a non-ideal way to grab the file name and move the files to another place.

```
tempPaths.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(rawStorePath, filter, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
```

The code above gets all the directories of all the files in the folder set. The outcome with be something like this. tempPaths is a List.

```
"./images/glass_numbers_5.jpg"
"./images/G.JPG"
"./images/E.JPG"
"./images/F.JPG"
"./images/glass_numbers_0.jpg"
"./images/C.JPG"
"./images/B.JPG"
"./images/A.JPG"
"./images/D.JPG"
"./images/glass_numbers_7.jpg"
```

then after i use a loop to grab the file names.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tempPaths.Count; i++)
                {
                    //Getting the original names of the images
                    int pLength = rawStorePath.Length;
                    string something = tempPaths[i].Remove(0, pLength);
                    if (!_tfileName.ContainsKey(tempPaths[i]))
                    { _tfileName.Add(tempPaths[i], something); }
                }
```

rawStorePath is the path of the targeted path e.g.: ./images/
tempPath[i] e.g. : ./images/G.JPG

So with the length i remove the letters and get the file name back.

Please advice me for a ideal way to do this if there is any.

Thanks!